# generate scalogram for a signal using continuous wavelet transform in python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, mathematical-optimization, wavelet-transform

I want to generate scalograms for my array (7680,).I am working from this site  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html I don't know how to get the parameters of this equation `scipy.signal.cwt(data, wavelet, widths)` for my array.

Answer (score 1):

```
# a rough solution here
from scipy import signal
y,sr=librosa.load("your audio  file.wav")
widths = np.arange(1, 128) # scales for morlet wavelet 
cwtmatr = signal.cwt(y, signal.morlet, widths) # the second parameter is where we are selecting a mother wavelet and the widths defines how many alterations on the mother wavelet needs to be performed to analyse the signal from different frequency resolutions, you should read more about them. 
plt.imshow(abs(cwtmatr), extent=[-1, 1, 31, 1],cmap='plasma', aspect='auto',
           vmax=abs(cwtmatr).max(),
           vmin=-abs(cwtmatr).min()) # finally we plot the scalogram
plt.show()
```

pywavelets library is more suitable for wavelet analysis tasks and then you can use matplotlib to plot scalograms.
there is this article which might also help you -- https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/audio-classification-using-wavelet-transform-and-deep-learning-f9f0978fa246